# Is there any way to flush the SSL write buffer

Tags: openssl

I have written one SSL client using OpenSSL APIs to interact with one SSL server. In OpenSSL site I learned that write buffer needs to be flushed after writing some data. I am using SSL_Write and SSL_Read in my client program. As OpenSSL site suggested I tried to flush the data using BIO_flush(BIO* ), I am getting crash here.

I am using the SSL libraries got from [this site](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android)

Here I am not clear about whether BIO_flush flashes the read buffer or write buffer..:-(
So I just wanted to know is there any other ways to flush the SSL write buffer...?

Here is the details about my client program.

1. Creating SSL object(mSsl) using SSL_new
2. Creating a TCP socket and making connection with server
3. Creating BIO object(mBio) using BIO_new_socket(socket_id,BIO_NOCLOSE)
4. Setting the BIO object to SSL object using SSL_set_bio(mSsl,mBio,mBio);
5. Setting the socket to SSL object using SSL_set_fd(mSsl,socket_id);
6. Making SSL connection with server using SSL_Connect(mSsl);

After the above steps I am starting two separate threads for write and read. Write thread uses SSL_write to write the data to server and Read thread uses SSL_Read to read the data from the server.

In Write thread after writing each packet using SSL_Write I am calling BIO_flush(mBio).

In whole program I am directly using mBio object only in this place for doing bio buffer flush.

When I do start sending the some packets, program in crashing in BIO_flush... As per the dump says its in BIO_ctrl function. I am not getting anything more than that.

Did any one used the library which I have provided link above and facing the same problem.. ? If yes please let me know if you know the solution.

Is there any thread synchronization rules to use BIO_flush()...? I mean call to BIO_flush SSL_Read should not happen at the same time like that... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIO_flush is used to flush write data.

Your mix and match of BIO_flush and SSL_read/write is problematic because the BIO structure is not aware of your SSL_read/write calls.

You'll get much better results from using BIO_read/write.

If you absolutely need to be using SSL_read/write you should avoid using BIOs.

I think you'll get much farther with the example at the end of this OpenSSL documentation.

[Simple OpenSSL Client Example](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BIO_s_connect.html)

If you're still getting crashes when trying that example, you might be having issues with the particular library build you are using.

Answer (score 10):

Where did you learn that the write buffer would need to be flushed after a write?

I was also looking for a flush function, but could not find one.

I think it works like this: Every call to SSL_write produces at least one SSL record and emits that out to the socket, where the nagle algorithm might buffer it in the kernel for a moment and quickly submits it to the outside.

So there is no buffering in SSL_write and therefore no flush!

I'd rather have a flush function and fill all SSL records to the brim, but that's not available as far as I see. I now plan to do my own buffering and to do as large calls to SSL_write as possible.

BTW: I just wrote a little test program: It sends a buffer with one write and then I ran it again, calling SSL_write for each character. Both times I run tcpdump and in Wireshark I could see that the first run had few large application data records and the second run had many small records. So I think it's confirmed.